# How create dataframe with

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with three columns date1, date2 and some_float;
I need to create dataframe with two columns: date_subtract(date1-date2) and some_int. Question is how to convert date (1.7.2015 17:26:23) into number of the day in year (188)?

My code:

```
      date1                   date2       some_float                                                           
1.7.2015 17:26:23      26.4.2015 14:46:33    2.99
5.5.2015 20:26:16      26.4.2015 14:46:33    2.99
29.4.2015 16:59:22     26.4.2015 14:46:33    2.99
13.5.2015 18:07:03     26.4.2015 14:46:33    6.99
4.5.2015 12:29:41      26.4.2015 14:46:33    6.99
30.4.2015 15:59:54     26.4.2015 14:46:33    2.99
6.5.2015 15:58:17      26.4.2015 14:46:33    2.99
2.5.2015 09:06:12      26.4.2015 14:46:33    2.99
```

I want:

```
date_dif           some_float
   72                 2.99
   9                  2.99
  ...                 ...
```

72 is 1.7.2015 - 26.4.2015 and 9 is 5.5.2015 - 26.4.2015

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, convert your columns representing dates to datetimes.

```
In [12]: df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], dayfirst=True)

In [13]: df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], dayfirst=True)
```

Then you can subtract the two columns directly to get a [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) representing the time elapsed.

```
In [14]: df['date1'] - df['date2']
Out[14]: 
0   66 days 02:39:50
1    9 days 05:39:43
2    3 days 02:12:49
3   17 days 03:20:30
4    7 days 21:43:08
5    4 days 01:13:21
6   10 days 01:11:44
7    5 days 18:19:39
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you just want the number of days, you can [convert](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion) like this, where `[D]` is the unit.

```
In [15]: (df['date1'] - df['date2']).astype('timedelta64[D]')
Out[15]: 
0    66
1     9
2     3
3    17
4     7
5     4
6    10
7     5
dtype: float64
```